# Find $P(A\cup B')$ and $P(A'\cup B)$ when $A,B$ are independent

Tags: probability, independence

I have solved an exercise but i have no idea if i am right or wrong.

> Find $P(A\cup B')$ and $P(A'\cup B)$ when $A,B$ are independent and $P(A)=0.2,\,P(B)=0.8.$

First I use $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$
So now $\;0.2+0.8-0.06=0.94.$
After this,  i think there is a type (i wasn't sure for this):

$$P(A)=1-P(A') \;\implies\; P(A')= -P(A)+1\;=-0.2+1\;=0.8,$$
$$P(B)=1-P(B') \;\implies\; P(B')= -P(B)+1\;=-0.8+1\;=0.2.$$

As a result to find what it asks me, i did this, but i am not sure if i am right on everything i did:

$$P(A\cup B')=P(A)+P(B')-P(A\cap B')= 0.2+0.2-(0.2)^2=\dots.$$
I did the same for $$P(A'\cup B)=P(A')+P(B)-P(A'\cap B)=\dots.$$

Comment: I'm not sure why your post was down-voted. It seems like you're doing them correctly with some minor mistakes. For example $P(AB) = 0.16$

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)=0.2+0.8-0.16=0.84$$

Your working seems fine but be careful of careless mistakes.

Note that independence is used so that we can compute the intersection probability $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: thanks a lot :)